Poincare section keeps running without giving results
I am trying to find the Poincare section as given in Figure 7 of this paper.
This is the code that I am using for it:
coordrep = {t -> t[\[Tau]], 
   r -> r[\[Tau]], \[Theta] -> \[Theta][\[Tau]], \[Phi] -> \[Phi][\
\[Tau]], t' -> t'[\[Tau]], 
   r' -> r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]' -> \[Theta]'[\[Tau]], \[Phi]' -> \
\[Phi]'[\[Tau]]};

lagrangian = -1/(
    2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]) (f[r] t'^2 - r'^2/f[r] - r^2 \[Theta]'^2 + 
      r^2 n^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) /. coordrep;

Pt = D[lagrangian, t'[\[Tau]]];

Pr = D[lagrangian, r'[\[Tau]]];

P\[Theta] = D[lagrangian, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]];

hamiltonian = ((Pt t'[\[Tau]] + Pr r'[\[Tau]] + 
        P\[Theta] \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]) - 
      lagrangian) /. (Solve[{pt[\[Tau]] == Pt, pr[\[Tau]] == Pr, 
        p\[Theta][\[Tau]] == P\[Theta]}, {t'[\[Tau]], 
        r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]}] // Last) // FullSimplify;

equations = {r'[\[Tau]] == +D[hamiltonian, 
       pr[\[Tau]]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] == +D[hamiltonian, 
       p\[Theta][\[Tau]]], pr'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, r[\[Tau]]], 
    p\[Theta]'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, \[Theta][\[Tau]]]} /. 
   pt[\[Tau]] -> En // Simplify

ClearAll[solution];
solution[R_, PR_] := 
  Reap@NDSolve[
    Flatten[{equations, {r[0] == R, pr[0] == PR, \[Theta][0] == 0, 
       p\[Theta][0] == initial[R, PR]}, 
      WhenEvent[\[Theta][\[Tau]] == 0 && \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] > 0, 
       Sow[{r[\[Tau]], pr[\[Tau]]}]]}], {}, {\[Tau], 0.0, \[Tau]max}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity];

\[Tau]max = 3000;

f[r_] = 1 - (2 M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + r^2/l^2;

ham = hamiltonian /. {t[\[Tau]] -> t, pt[\[Tau]] -> pt, 
    r[\[Tau]] -> r, pr[\[Tau]] -> pr, \[Theta][\[Tau]] -> \[Theta], 
    p\[Theta][\[Tau]] -> p\[Theta]} /. pt -> En

En = 12; M = 1/2; \[Alpha] = 1/\[Pi]; n = 1; l = 15; Q = 0.2;

constraint = (p\[Theta] /. 
     Solve[(En == ham) /. \[Theta] -> 0, p\[Theta]]) // Last;

ClearAll[initial];
initial[r_?NumericQ, pr_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[constraint]

ListPlot[Table[solution[R, 3.6] // Last // First, {R, 6, 12, 1}], 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[0.004]}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> Large, GridLines -> None]

I am not sure why, but it's taking forever to run. Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial.
Edit: Another approach using ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D"]
coordrep = {t -> t[\[Tau]], 
   r -> r[\[Tau]], \[Theta] -> \[Theta][\[Tau]], \[Phi] -> \[Phi][\
\[Tau]], t' -> t'[\[Tau]], 
   r' -> r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]' -> \[Theta]'[\[Tau]], \[Phi]' -> \
\[Phi]'[\[Tau]]};

lagrangian = -1/(
    2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]) (f[r] t'^2 - r'^2/f[r] - r^2 \[Theta]'^2 + 
      r^2 n^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) /. coordrep;

Pt = D[lagrangian, t'[\[Tau]]];

Pr = D[lagrangian, r'[\[Tau]]];

P\[Theta] = D[lagrangian, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]];

(Pt t'[\[Tau]] + Pr r'[\[Tau]] + P\[Theta] \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]) - 
  lagrangian;

hamiltonian = ((Pt t'[\[Tau]] + Pr r'[\[Tau]] + 
        P\[Theta] \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]) - 
      lagrangian) /. (Solve[{pt[\[Tau]] == Pt, pr[\[Tau]] == Pr, 
        p\[Theta][\[Tau]] == P\[Theta]}, {t'[\[Tau]], 
        r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]}] // Last) // FullSimplify;

{a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1} = {D[hamiltonian, pt[\[Tau]]], 
  D[hamiltonian, pr[\[Tau]]], 
  D[hamiltonian, 
   p\[Theta][\[Tau]]], -D[hamiltonian, t[\[Tau]]], -D[hamiltonian, 
    r[\[Tau]]], -D[
    hamiltonian, \[Theta][\[Tau]]]}; hameqns = {t'[\[Tau]] == a1, 
  pt'[\[Tau]] == d1, r'[\[Tau]] == b1, 
  pr'[\[Tau]] == e1, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] == c1, 
  p\[Theta]'[\[Tau]] == f1};

cross = \[Theta][\[Tau]]; recover = {r[\[Tau]], pr[\[Tau]]};

f[r_] = 1 - (2 M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + r^2/l^2;

ham = hamiltonian /. {t[\[Tau]] -> t, pt[\[Tau]] -> pt, 
    r[\[Tau]] -> r, pr[\[Tau]] -> pr, \[Theta][\[Tau]] -> \[Theta], 
    p\[Theta][\[Tau]] -> p\[Theta]} /. pt -> En

En = 12; M = 1/2; \[Alpha] = 1/\[Pi]; n = 1; l = 15;

H = ResourceFunction["ScalarPureFunction"][
   ham, {r, pr, \[Theta], p\[Theta]}];

eq1 = hameqns[[3]]

eq2 = hameqns[[4]] /. pt[\[Tau]] -> En

eq3 = hameqns[[5]]

eq4 = hameqns[[6]]

Block[{Q = 0.2}, 
 ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D"][{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4}, H, 
  12, \[Tau], 8000, cross, 
  recover, {PlotStyle -> PointSize[.004], AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> {{5, 13}, {3, 6}}, PlotHighlighting -> None}]]

How can I get a similar result from the first approach which I got from the second approach?

It could be better to use Module for parametric research as follows
coordrep = {t -> t[\[Tau]], 
   r -> r[\[Tau]], \[Theta] -> \[Theta][\[Tau]], \[Phi] -> \[Phi][\
\[Tau]], t' -> t'[\[Tau]], 
   r' -> r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]' -> \[Theta]'[\[Tau]], \[Phi]' -> \
\[Phi]'[\[Tau]]};

lagrangian = -1/(2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]) (f[r] t'^2 - r'^2/f[r] - 
      r^2 \[Theta]'^2 + r^2 n^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) /. coordrep;

Pt = D[lagrangian, t'[\[Tau]]];

Pr = D[lagrangian, r'[\[Tau]]];

P\[Theta] = D[lagrangian, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]];

hamiltonian = ((Pt t'[\[Tau]] + Pr r'[\[Tau]] + 
       P\[Theta] \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]) - 
     lagrangian) /. (Solve[{pt[\[Tau]] == Pt, pr[\[Tau]] == Pr, 
       p\[Theta][\[Tau]] == P\[Theta]}, {t'[\[Tau]], 
       r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]}] // Last);

equations = {r'[\[Tau]] == 
    D[hamiltonian, pr[\[Tau]]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] == 
    D[hamiltonian, p\[Theta][\[Tau]]], 
   pr'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, r[\[Tau]]], 
   p\[Theta]'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, \[Theta][\[Tau]]]} /. 
  pt[\[Tau]] -> En


(*Out[]= {Derivative[1][
   r][\[Tau]] == \[Pi] \[Alpha] f[r[\[Tau]]] pr[\[Tau]], 
 Derivative[
   1][\[Theta]][\[Tau]] == (\[Pi] \[Alpha] p\[Theta][\[Tau]])/
  r[\[Tau]]^2, 
 Derivative[1][pr][\[Tau]] == (2 \[Pi] \[Alpha] p\[Theta][\[Tau]]^2)/
   r[\[Tau]]^3 - (En^2 \[Pi] \[Alpha] Derivative[1][f][r[\[Tau]]])/
   f[r[\[Tau]]]^2 - \[Pi] \[Alpha] pr[\[Tau]]^2 Derivative[1][f][
     r[\[Tau]]] - ((2 \[Pi]^2 \[Alpha]^2 p\[Theta][\[Tau]]^2)/
    r[\[Tau]]^3 + 2 n^2 r[\[Tau]] Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]]^2 - (
    En^2 \[Pi]^2 \[Alpha]^2 Derivative[1][f][r[\[Tau]]])/
    f[r[\[Tau]]]^2 - \[Pi]^2 \[Alpha]^2 pr[\[Tau]]^2 Derivative[1][f][
      r[\[Tau]]])/(2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]), 
 Derivative[1][p\[Theta]][\[Tau]] == -((
   n^2 Cos[\[Theta][\[Tau]]] r[\[Tau]]^2 \
Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]])/(\[Pi] \[Alpha]))}*)
ham = hamiltonian /. {t[\[Tau]] -> t, pt[\[Tau]] -> pt, 
    r[\[Tau]] -> R, pr[\[Tau]] -> PR, \[Theta][\[Tau]] -> \[Theta], 
    p\[Theta][\[Tau]] -> p\[Theta]} /. 
  pt -> En; constraint = (p\[Theta] /. 
    Solve[(En == ham) /. \[Theta] -> 0, p\[Theta]]) // Last


(*(R Sqrt[En^2 \[Pi] \[Alpha] + 
  2 En f[R] - \[Pi] PR^2 \[Alpha] f[
    R]^2])/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[\[Alpha]] Sqrt[f[R]])*)
data[En_, R_, PR_, Q_] := 
 Module[{\[Tau]max = 3000, M = 1/2, \[Alpha] = 1/\[Pi], n = 1, 
   l = 15}, f = Function[r, 1 - (2 M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + r^2/l^2]; 
  eqs = {Derivative[1][
      r][\[Tau]] == \[Pi]  \[Alpha]  f[r[\[Tau]]]  pr[\[Tau]], 
    Derivative[
      1][\[Theta]][\[Tau]] == (\[Pi] \[Alpha] p\[Theta][\[Tau]])/
     r[\[Tau]]^2, 
    Derivative[1][pr][\[Tau]] == (
      2 \[Pi] \[Alpha] p\[Theta][\[Tau]]^2)/r[\[Tau]]^3 - (
      En^2 \[Pi] \[Alpha] Derivative[1][f][r[\[Tau]]])/
      f[r[\[Tau]]]^2 - \[Pi]  \[Alpha]  pr[\[Tau]]^2  Derivative[1][
        f][r[\[Tau]]] - ((2 \[Pi]^2 \[Alpha]^2 p\[Theta][\[Tau]]^2)/
       r[\[Tau]]^3 + 2 n^2 r[\[Tau]] Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]]^2 - (
       En^2 \[Pi]^2 \[Alpha]^2 Derivative[1][f][r[\[Tau]]])/
       f[r[\[Tau]]]^2 - \[Pi]^2 \[Alpha]^2 pr[\[Tau]]^2 Derivative[1][
         f][r[\[Tau]]])/(2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]), 
    Derivative[1][p\[Theta]][\[Tau]] == -((
      n^2 Cos[\[Theta][\[Tau]]] r[\[Tau]]^2 Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]])/(\
\[Pi] \[Alpha]))}; 
  ini = {r[0] == R, pr[0] == PR, \[Theta][0] == 0, 
    p\[Theta][0] == (
     R Sqrt[En^2 \[Pi] \[Alpha] + 
       2 En f[R] - \[Pi] PR^2 \[Alpha] f[R]^2])/(
     Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[\[Alpha]] Sqrt[f[R]])}; 
  dat = Reap@
    NDSolve[{Join[eqs, ini], 
      WhenEvent[\[Theta][\[Tau]] == 0 && \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] > 0, 
       Sow[{r[\[Tau]], pr[\[Tau]]}]]}, {}, {\[Tau], 0.0, \[Tau]max}, 
     MaxSteps -> Infinity]; dat // Last // First]

Now we can reproduce Figure 7 and 8 from the paper
Q0 = {0.001, 0.2, 0.45, 0.4987};

ListPlot[data[12, 10, 3.6, #], PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[0.01]}],
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, GridLines -> None, 
   FrameLabel -> {"R", "Pr"}] & /@ Q0


ListPlot[Table[data[En, 10, 3.6, .2], {En, {11.5, 12, 12.5}}], 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[0.01]}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, GridLines -> None, 
 FrameLabel -> {"R", "Pr"}]


Update 1. To generate many orbits, we need to modify code so that to avoid long computation, so we have
data[En_, R_, PR_, Q_] := 
 Module[{\[Tau]max = 3000, M = 1/2, \[Alpha] = 1/\[Pi], n = 1, 
   l = 15}, f = Function[r, 1 - (2  M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + r^2/l^2]; 
  eqs = {Derivative[1][
      r][\[Tau]] == \[Pi]  \[Alpha]  f[r[\[Tau]]]  pr[\[Tau]], 
    Derivative[
      1][\[Theta]][\[Tau]] == (\[Pi] \[Alpha] p\[Theta][\[Tau]])/
     r[\[Tau]]^2, 
    Derivative[1][pr][\[Tau]] == (
      2 \[Pi] \[Alpha] p\[Theta][\[Tau]]^2)/r[\[Tau]]^3 - (
      En^2 \[Pi] \[Alpha] Derivative[1][f][r[\[Tau]]])/
      f[r[\[Tau]]]^2 - \[Pi]  \[Alpha]  pr[\[Tau]]^2  Derivative[1][
        f][r[\[Tau]]] - ((2 \[Pi]^2 \[Alpha]^2 p\[Theta][\[Tau]]^2)/
       r[\[Tau]]^3 + 2 n^2 r[\[Tau]] Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]]^2 - (
       En^2 \[Pi]^2 \[Alpha]^2 Derivative[1][f][r[\[Tau]]])/
       f[r[\[Tau]]]^2 - \[Pi]^2 \[Alpha]^2 pr[\[Tau]]^2 Derivative[1][
         f][r[\[Tau]]])/(2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]), 
    Derivative[1][p\[Theta]][\[Tau]] == -((
      n^2 Cos[\[Theta][\[Tau]]] r[\[Tau]]^2 Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]])/(\
\[Pi] \[Alpha]))}; 
  ini = {r[0] == R, pr[0] == PR, \[Theta][0] == 0, 
    p\[Theta][0] == (
     R Sqrt[En^2 \[Pi] \[Alpha] + 
       2 En f[R] - \[Pi] PR^2 \[Alpha] f[R]^2])/(
     Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[\[Alpha]] Sqrt[f[R]])}; 
  dat = Reap@
    Quiet@NDSolve[{Join[eqs, ini], 
       WhenEvent[\[Theta][\[Tau]] == 0 && \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] > 0, 
        Sow[{r[\[Tau]], pr[\[Tau]]}]]}, {}, {\[Tau], 0.0, \[Tau]max}, 
      MaxSteps -> 5  10^4, MaxStepSize -> 0.2, 
      Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]; dat // Last // First]

Example of usage
set = Table[
    data[12, R, Pr, .2], {R, 10, 11, .2}, {Pr, 3.2, 
     4.2, .2}]; // AbsoluteTiming

It takes about 112s on my very slow Silver Pentium. Visualization
ListPlot[Flatten[set, 1], PlotRange -> {{4, 14}, {3, 6}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[0.0025]}],
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, GridLines -> None, 
 FrameLabel -> {"R", "Pr"}, Background -> Black]



Thank you, Alex, for the answer. Just one query: what if I wish to make an entire Poincare section, not just a section for specific given values?

Alex please see the edited Question :)

@codebpr Sorry, but I don't understand you. Did you asked this question: "I am trying to find the Poincare section as given in Figure 7"? :)

My sincere apologies. I meant to say that using the initial conditions like Figure 7. They just use one initial condition, which, to me, makes the section less aesthetic. What if I wish to take many? Would using a table in your code be the most efficient way, or would you discard the module altogether?

@codebpr I see that you are not really want to reproduce Figure 7 but would like to make something else, as for example many orbits generated by second code. Is it correct?

Yes, exactly. Thank you for the update.

I have one issue. Suppose I wish to change the range of R and Pr for example, say: set = Table[data[12, R, Pr, .2], {R, 9, 11, .2}, {Pr, 3.2, 4.2, .2}] I get some errors in such cases and not able to get the plot.

@codebpr Actually this system has unstably solutions, it is why in the paper they used fixed initial conditions. Therefore, we need some stability analysis. Maybe we can do this, but not in this topic.
