Poincare section and chaos
I have the following system of differential equations :
Derivative[1][
  r][\[Tau]] == {-(pr[\[Tau]]/(2 Sqrt[1 + 1/r[\[Tau]]^4]))};
Derivative[
  1][\[Phi]1][\[Tau]] == {-(p\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]/(
   2 Sqrt[1 + 1/r[\[Tau]]^4] r[\[Tau]]^2))};
Derivative[1][
  pr][\[Tau]] == {p\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]^2/(
   2 (1 + 1/r[\[Tau]]^4)^(3/2) r[\[Tau]]^7) + pr[\[Tau]]^2/(
   2 (1 + 1/r[\[Tau]]^4)^(3/2) r[\[Tau]]^5) + 2/(
   Sqrt[1 + 1/r[\[Tau]]^4] r[\[Tau]]^5) - p\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]^2/(
   2 Sqrt[1 + 1/r[\[Tau]]^4] r[\[Tau]]^3) - (
   2 n5^2 Sin[\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]]^2)/(
   Sqrt[1 + 1/r[\[Tau]]^4] r[\[Tau]]^3) + 
   2 n5^2 Sqrt[1 + 1/r[\[Tau]]^4] r[\[Tau]] Sin[\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]]^2};
Derivative[1][
  p\[Phi]1][\[Tau]] == {2 n5^2 Cos[\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]] Sqrt[
   1 + 1/r[\[Tau]]^4] r[\[Tau]]^2 Sin[\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]]};

Using the Reap-Sow, I was trying to obtain the Poinacre section for the system I have using the following code :
coordrep = {t -> t[\[Tau]], 
   r -> r[\[Tau]], \[Phi]1 -> \[Phi]1[\[Tau]], t' -> t'[\[Tau]], 
   r' -> r'[\[Tau]], \[Phi]1' -> \[Phi]1'[\[Tau]]};

lagrangian = 
 t'^2/Sqrt[f[r]] - Sqrt[f[r]] r'^2 - Sqrt[f[r]] r^2* \[Phi]1'^2  + 
   Sqrt[f[r]] r^2 Sin[\[Phi]1]^2 n5^2 /. coordrep

Clear[\[Sigma]]

Pt = D[lagrangian, t'[\[Tau]]];

Pr = D[lagrangian, r'[\[Tau]]];

P\[Phi]1 = D[lagrangian, \[Phi]1'[\[Tau]]];

Clear[f]

hamiltonian = ((Pt t'[\[Tau]] + Pr r'[\[Tau]] + 
        P\[Phi]1 \[Phi]1'[\[Tau]]) - 
      lagrangian) /. (Solve[{pt[\[Tau]] == Pt, pr[\[Tau]] == Pr, 
        p\[Phi]1[\[Tau]] == P\[Phi]1}, {t'[\[Tau]], 
        r'[\[Tau]], \[Phi]1'[\[Tau]]}] // Last) /. pt[\[Tau]] -> En // Expand

Clear[f, En, a, b, c, n, l, \[Alpha]]

f[x_] := 1 + (\[Alpha] R0^4)/x^4

equations = {r'[\[Tau]] == 
   D[hamiltonian, pr[\[Tau]]], \[Phi]1'[\[Tau]] == 
   D[hamiltonian, p\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]], 
  pr'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, r[\[Tau]]], 
  p\[Phi]1'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, \[Phi]1[\[Tau]]]}

ham = 
 hamiltonian /. {r[\[Tau]] -> R, 
   pr[\[Tau]] -> PR, \[Phi]1[\[Tau]] -> \[CapitalPhi], 
   px[\[Tau]] -> P\[CapitalPhi]}

Clear[En]

constraint = (PR /. 
    Solve[(0 == ham) /. \[CapitalPhi] -> 0, PR]) // Last

data[R_, p\[Phi]10_, En_] := 
 Module[{\[Tau]max = 24.405, M = 1/2, \[Alpha] = 1, n5 = 1, l = 15, 
   R0 = 1}, f = Function[r, 1 + (\[Alpha] R0^4)/r^4];
  eqs = {Derivative[1][r][\[Tau]] == -(pr[\[Tau]]/(
      2 Sqrt[1 + (R0^4 \[Alpha])/r[\[Tau]]^4])), 
    Derivative[1][\[Phi]1][\[Tau]] == -(p\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]/(
      2 Sqrt[1 + (R0^4 \[Alpha])/r[\[Tau]]^4] r[\[Tau]]^2)), 
    Derivative[1][pr][\[Tau]] == (R0^4 \[Alpha] p\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]^2)/(
      2 (1 + (R0^4 \[Alpha])/r[\[Tau]]^4)^(3/2) r[\[Tau]]^7) + (
      R0^4 \[Alpha] pr[\[Tau]]^2)/(
      2 (1 + (R0^4 \[Alpha])/r[\[Tau]]^4)^(3/2) r[\[Tau]]^5) + (
      En^2 R0^4 \[Alpha])/(
      2 Sqrt[1 + (R0^4 \[Alpha])/r[\[Tau]]^4] r[\[Tau]]^5) - 
      p\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]^2/(
      2 Sqrt[1 + (R0^4 \[Alpha])/r[\[Tau]]^4] r[\[Tau]]^3) - (
      2 n5^2 R0^4 \[Alpha] Sin[\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]]^2)/(
      Sqrt[1 + (R0^4 \[Alpha])/r[\[Tau]]^4] r[\[Tau]]^3) + 
      2 n5^2 Sqrt[1 + (R0^4 \[Alpha])/r[\[Tau]]^4]
        r[\[Tau]] Sin[\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]]^2, 
    Derivative[1][p\[Phi]1][\[Tau]] == 
     2 n5^2 Cos[\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]] Sqrt[1 + (R0^4 \[Alpha])/r[\[Tau]]^4]
       r[\[Tau]]^2 Sin[\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]]};
  ini = {r[0] == R, 
    pr[0] == Sqrt[En^2 + En^2/R^4 - p\[Phi]10^2/R^2], \[Phi]1[0] == 0,
     p\[Phi]1[0] == p\[Phi]10};
  dat = Reap@
    NDSolve[{Join[eqs, ini], 
      WhenEvent[\[Phi]1[\[Tau]] == 0 && \[Phi]1'[\[Tau]] > 0, 
       Sow[{r[\[Tau]], pr[\[Tau]]}]]}, {}, {\[Tau], 0.0, \[Tau]max}, 
     MaxSteps -> Infinity]; dat // Last // First]

En = {0.9};

ListPlot[data[12.0, 3.2, #], PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[0.01]}],
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, GridLines -> None, 
   FrameLabel -> {"R", "Pr"}] & /@ En

What I am interested in is to find the Poicare section similar to this see fig 7, page 9 of this paper. But I am not getting it. I don't know what is wrong with this code that I am not getting it. One of the things could be that I cannot guess the right initial conditions. But I am not sure whether that is the reason or not. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.
UPDATE 1: The recent what I have checked is to see if I have the corresponding phase space as oscillatory using the following code:
En = 10;
\[Tau]max = 70.5; n5 = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{equations, {r[0] == 12, pr[0] == 0.4, \[Phi]1[0] == 0, 
     p\[Phi]1[0] == 
      119.90685737039581`(*p\[Phi]1value*)}}, \
{\!\(TraditionalForm\`r[\[Tau]]\), \[Phi]1[\[Tau]], pr[\[Tau]], 
    p\[Phi]1[\[Tau]]}, {\[Tau], 0 , \[Tau]max}][[1]]
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{r[\[Tau]], \[Tau]} /. sol], {\[Tau], 0, \[Tau]max}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2]

The output is as follows for r-pr plot

We can see that the phase space is not fully oscillaoty and it decays upto a certian time tau, and after that the system gets stiff. Now if we draw the Poincare now upto the same time, we get

and if I draw it over a range of R from using the code
P1 = ListPlot[Table[data[R, 0, 10], {R, 12, 20.2, 0.05}], 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[0.003]}], 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, GridLines -> None, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]\)"}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]

I get the following plot:

Now I am not sure is it the correct plot corresponding to the decaying type phase space of r-pr ? If not, what possible modification one can do to get the correct Poincare section?

Duplicate: Poincare section keeps running without giving results

@E.Chan-López  I implemented that code for my system but I don't understand that why it worked there but not in my case. Any help is greatly appreciated pls.

@fusis-desire Why not to use my code as it is? :)  Please note this system has unstably solutions, it is why in the paper they used fixed initial conditions.

@AlexTrounev Thank you for your reply. I have seen your code and used it also for this paper:https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.04466. But my question is when I use the same code with some modifications for my system, I am not getting similar plots. Is it because of the initial conditions ? Or I am missing something?

@fusis-desire First, you need to find the area of ​​chaotic behavior.

@AlexTrounev You mean the area of the phase space of (r,pr) ?

@fusis-desire Yes, we need some stability analysis before making Poincare section.  Please, pay attention, that there is nothing chaotic in your plot. Or maybe your question not about chaos. :)

@AlexTrounev I agree with the Poincare plots, which I am getting I can't say anything about the chaos. But if we draw the Lyapunov exponent for this system, I am getting the Largest Lyapunov exponent to be positive, which thus indicates the chaos.

@fusis-desire If you agree then what is your question about? :) Please answer, how is the system you use different from the one I used in my answer here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/306540/poincare-section-keeps-running-without-giving-results ?

@AlexTrounev My system and the one you used in that answer have the same structure ie both are in 4d and the Poincare section is observed at angular coordinate->0. And as a matter of fact, since they look similar, I don't understand why I am not getting the Poincare section in this system...first I thought I am not hitting the right initial conditions and so I am not getting it, but now it seems as you have indicated that Poincare section is not enough to conclude the about chaos in this system. Am I correct in making such statement, Alex?

@fusis-desire In your model f[x_] := 1 + (\[Alpha] R0^4)/x^4, while in the paper they used  f = Function[r, 1 - (2  M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + r^2/l^2] for the Reissner-Nordstrom (RN) black hole in AdS4 spacetime, and f= Function[r, 1 - (2  M)/r + Q^2/r^2 ] for Reissner-Nordstrom (RN) blackhole in asymptotically flat space-time.

@AlexTrounev Oh! you were asking about that. Yes, that is correct, the f-function is different in both of the cases.

There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is that the output is too small to see the details. Enlarge the picture and you will see:


I was getting this plot, but what I am interested in is finding a plot similar to this paper https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.95.066014 ,( see fig 7 page number 7) ie which follows the KAM theorem.

@fusis-desire your paper is behind a paywall. Is there an arXiv version?

@mattiav27 yes it has an arxiv version. Here it is: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.04466 (page 9, fig 7)
